# extract set of values from multidimensional array using an index

Tags: php

I've a standard array which only contains a list of IDs and I have a multidimensional array which contains a set of values (ID, name, surname).
What I'm trying to do is to extract from the multidimensional array the whole set of values only for the IDs present in the first array.
Example:

```
    $array1 = "1","2","12","43","52";

    $array2 = {[0]"id"=>"12","name"=>"Robert","surname"=>"Plant";[1]"id"=>"43","name"=>"Jimmy","surname"=>"Page";[2]"id"=>"8","name"=>"Mary","surname"=>"Stilton";}
```

I need to get an array which contains

```
    {[0]"id"=>"12","name"=>"Robert","surname"=>"Plant";[1]"id"=>"43","name"=>"Jimmy","surname"=>"Page";}
```

I've tried different solutions, using a foreach cycle, but I'm not getting the required output.

What I've tried:
$idpresent is the array with the IDs list, $globalarray is the multidimensional array.

```
foreach($idpresent as $test){
    if(in_array($test,$globalarray["id"])){
        echo $globalarray["name"];
    }
}
```

But I'm getting no output.
Can anybody kindly help?

Comment: That's not valid PHP code

Comment: Please post what you already tried and where that code fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following logic might help you on your way: cycle through the whitelist (`$array1`) and if `id` is present in `$array2` store the resulting record in `$result` array.

```
<?php
$array1 = ["1","2","12","43","52"];

$array2 = [
    ["id"=>"12","name"=>"Robert","surname"=>"Plant"],
    ["id"=>"43","name"=>"Jimmy","surname"=>"Page"],
    ["id"=>"8","name"=>"Mary","surname"=>"Stilton"]
    ];

$result = []; // result store
foreach($array1 as $whitelisted) {
    foreach($array2 as $record) {
        if($record['id'] == $whitelisted) $result[] = $record;
    }
}
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/Au6XH)

Comment: thanks a lot for this easy and clean solution.. I spent many hours trying to figure out how to do that and you did the magic :)

Comment: Glad I could help!